# Selenium: resize window in a tiling window manager

Tags: selenium

I'm using a tiling window manager i3 to run selenium tests. Sometimes I run tests using Chrome & Firefox besides PhantomJS. I realize that one cannot resize an i3 window that's tiled, so I wonder what, if any, workarounds are there to resize window, or detecting if the window is currently tiled and setting it floating?

I realize that one option would be setting chrome and firefox to always run floating in i3 config, but that would impede my regular workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually *can* resize tiled windows, either with the mouse or with [the `resize` command](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#resizingconfig):

```
resize <grow|shrink> <up|down|left|right|height|width> [<px> px [or <ppt> ppt]]
```

This grows or shrinks the window in the given direction. With the optional parameters you can specify by what amount the window should be resized. The first argument - `<px> px` - is used for floating windows and defaults to `10 px`. The second argument - `<ppt> ppt` is for tiled windows and gives the amount in percentage points of the parent container, it defaults to `10 ppt`.

In the default configuration there is a `resize` mode that can be reach with <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> (with <kbd>Mod</kbd> being either <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>, depending on the choice when first starting `i3`). While in this mode, windows - floating and tiled - can be grown with <kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> and shrunken with <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Left</kbd>.

For example: Say, you have a container with 3 equally wide windows side-by-side - each taking 33.33 % of the containers width. If you run `resize grow width` on the middle one, it will be resized to take 43.33 % of the parent container, while the windows to either side will be shrunken to 28.33 %.

---

As for setting a window to floating, you can always do that with the [command `floating enable`](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_manipulating_layout), so there is actually no need to query the current floating state.

---

If you really want to, you could query this information from [*i3's* IPC interface](http://i3wm.org/docs/ipc.html).

**Proof of concept:**

1. Use `i3-msg -t get_tree` to retrieve the JSON-encoded layout tree (this gets you the whole JSON in one line, so maybe you want to put it through `json_xs`, `json_pp` or some similar program for more human-friendliness).
2. Get the ID of the current window with `xdotool getactivewindow`
3. Look in the tree for a node with attribute `"window": <WINDOWID>`
4. Check whether the attribute `"floating"` is set to `"user_on"` (or possibly `"<ANYTHING>_on"`, I am not sure about that)

Comment: Thanks. You're right and windows can be resized in the direction they are stacked with against windows, but not freely which is what I need for testing.

Comment: Thanks for writing a detailed answer. I'm marking this answer as correct with my previous comment as a caveat.